# PHP determine whether PDO execute() returns data or performed an action

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm using the following code in a DB class to run queries for the rest of a PHP application:

```
public function query($sql, $parameters = [])
    {
        try
        {
        $this->setError(false);
        $stmt = $this->getPdo()->prepare($sql); //assign to a variable with a short name
        if ($stmt):
            $x = 1;
            if (count($parameters)):
                foreach($parameters as $parameter):
                    $stmt->bindValue($x, $parameter);
                $x++;
                endforeach;
            endif;
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->setResults($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
            $this->setCount($stmt->rowCount());
        endif;
        return $this;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $this->setError(true);
            throw $e;
        }

}
```

It seems to work just find for SELECT queries.  However, when SQL statement involving an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE uses it this method works (as in it performs the action on the data in the database) but it displays a fatal error citing an uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message  **SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.**  It says the exception is thrown by this line:

```
$this->setResults($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
```

Is there a way the above code can be modified to determine whether execute() performed a SELECT vs. an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE and only perform the fetchAll() for SELECT statements?

Note: the database being used in MS SQL Server

Comment: why do you need setResults and rowCount methods? Why not just return  $stmt, which will not only solve ALL your problems at once but also shorten your code DRASTICALLY?

Comment: Question is not worthy of answer.SEE [**PDO info**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for lazy binding ie`$stmt->execute($parameters);`.

Comment: @davidstrachan I don't understand why you said to look at lazy binding.  Please explain.

Comment: @knot22 From link in comment Use "lazy" binding when possible - passing data into execute will dramatically shorten your code.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out:

```
public function query($sql, $parameters = [])
{
    try
    {
    $this->setError(false);
    $stmt = $this->getPdo()->prepare($sql); //assign to a variable with a short name
    if ($stmt):
        $x = 1;
        if (count($parameters)):
            foreach($parameters as $parameter):
                $stmt->bindValue($x, $parameter);
            $x++;
            endforeach;
        endif;
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->setCount($stmt->rowCount()); //for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE stmts this is number of rows that were affected, displays -1 for SELECT stmt
        if ($stmt->rowCount() == -1):       //conditionally do the following if SQL stmt was a SELECT
            $this->setResults($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
            $this->setCount($stmt->rowCount()); //overwrite count attribute with number of rows returned by SELECT stmt
        endif;
    endif;
    return $this;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $this->setError(true);
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: second call for setCount looks extremely useful